# limiting number of rollover files using rollingfileappender

Tags: log4j

I am using log4j extras to log my rotates every day using following configuration:

```
log4j.appender.abclog=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.abclog.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.abclog.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/opa/abc-home/logs/xyz-abc_t.log  
log4j.appender.abclog.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/opa/abc-home/logs/xyz-abc_t-.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz  
log4j.appender.abclog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.abclog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

However, I am having issues to limit the number of rollover files using MaxBackupIndex. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using the standard API of log4j or even  with the extras <sup>**1**</sup>.

However, you can use the class [**`org.apache.log4j.DailyMaxRollingFileAppender`**](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender) <sup>**2**</sup>, e.g.:

```
log4j.appender.abclog=org.apache.log4j.DailyMaxRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.abclog.File=/opa/abc-home/logs/xyz-abc_t.log
log4j.appender.abclog.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.abclog.DatePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.abclog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.abclog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

---

*Notes*

1. *Apache Extras™ for Apache log4j™* in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/
2. See the code of this class in [*Custom DailyRollingFileAppender with MaxBackupIndex*](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender).

Comment: Worth mentioning that [documentation says](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) that "DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss"